# Get subset of most frequent dummy variables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform some linear regression analysis, I have some categorical features that i convert to dummy variables using the super awesome get_dummies.

The issue I face is, the dataframe gets too big when I add all the elements of the categories.

Is there a way (using get_dummies or a more elaborate method) to just create dummy variables of the most frequent terms instead of all of them?

Answer (score 8):

use `value_counts()` to do the frequency counting, and then create a mask for the rows that you want remain:

```
import pandas as pd
values = pd.Series(["a","b","a","b","c","d","e","a"])
counts = pd.value_counts(values)
mask = values.isin(counts[counts > 1].index)
print pd.get_dummies(values[mask])
```

output:

```
   a  b
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  0  1
7  1  0
```

if you want all the data:

```
values[~mask] = "-"
print pd.get_dummies(values)
```

output:

```
   -  a  b
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  1
4  1  0  0
5  1  0  0
6  1  0  0
7  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 5):

I used the answer that [@HYRY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18017283/3671347) gave to write a function that will have a parameter (threshold) that can be used to separate the popular values and unpopular ones (combined in 'others' column).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# func that returns a dummified DataFrame of significant dummies in a given column
def dum_sign(dummy_col, threshold=0.1):

    # removes the bind
    dummy_col = dummy_col.copy()

    # what is the ratio of a dummy in whole column
    count = pd.value_counts(dummy_col) / len(dummy_col)

    # cond whether the ratios is higher than the threshold
    mask = dummy_col.isin(count[count > threshold].index)

    # replace the ones which ratio is lower than the threshold by a special name
    dummy_col[~mask] = "others"

    return pd.get_dummies(dummy_col, prefix=dummy_col.name)
#
```

Let's create some data:

```
df = ['a', 'a', np.nan, np.nan, 'a', np.nan, 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 
             'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g']

data = pd.Series(df, name='dums')
```

Examples of use:

```
 In: dum_sign(data)
Out:
    dums_a  dums_b  dums_g  dums_others
0        1       0       0            0
1        1       0       0            0
2        0       0       0            1
3        0       0       0            1
4        1       0       0            0
5        0       0       0            1
6        1       0       0            0
7        0       1       0            0
8        0       1       0            0
9        0       1       0            0
10       0       1       0            0
11       0       1       0            0
12       0       0       0            1
13       0       0       0            1
14       0       0       0            1
15       0       0       0            1
16       0       0       1            0
17       0       0       1            0
18       0       0       1            0
19       0       0       1            0

 In: dum_sign(data, threshold=0.2)
Out: 
    dums_b  dums_others
0        0            1
1        0            1
2        0            1
3        0            1
4        0            1
5        0            1
6        0            1
7        1            0
8        1            0
9        1            0
10       1            0
11       1            0
12       0            1
13       0            1
14       0            1
15       0            1
16       0            1
17       0            1
18       0            1
19       0            1

 In: dum_sign(data, threshold=0)
Out: 
    dums_a  dums_b  dums_c  dums_d  dums_e  dums_g  dums_others
0        1       0       0       0       0       0            0
1        1       0       0       0       0       0            0
2        0       0       0       0       0       0            1
3        0       0       0       0       0       0            1
4        1       0       0       0       0       0            0
5        0       0       0       0       0       0            1
6        1       0       0       0       0       0            0
7        0       1       0       0       0       0            0
8        0       1       0       0       0       0            0
9        0       1       0       0       0       0            0
10       0       1       0       0       0       0            0
11       0       1       0       0       0       0            0
12       0       0       1       0       0       0            0
13       0       0       1       0       0       0            0
14       0       0       0       1       0       0            0
15       0       0       0       0       1       0            0
16       0       0       0       0       0       1            0
17       0       0       0       0       0       1            0
18       0       0       0       0       0       1            0
19       0       0       0       0       0       1            0
```

Any suggestions how to handle nans? I believe that nans should not be treated as 'others'.

UPD: I have tested it on a pretty large dataset (5 mil obs) with 183 different strings in the column that I wanted to dummify. The implementation takes 10 sec max on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You could first use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to see which are the most frequent:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(list('aabccc'))

In [12]: s
Out[12]: 
0    a
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    c
5    c
dtype: object

In [13]: s.value_counts()
Out[13]: 
c    3
a    2
b    1
dtype: int64
```

The values which are the least frequent (e.g. all except the first two):

```
In [14]: s.value_counts().index[2:]
Out[14]: Index([u'b'], dtype=object)
```

You can simply [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) all of these occurences with NaN:

```
In [15]: s1 = s.replace(s.value_counts().index[2:], np.nan)

In [16]: s1
Out[16]: 
0      a
1      a
2    NaN
3      c
4      c
5      c
dtype: object
```

and perform `get_dummies` (which I *think* ought to ignore the NaN, but there is a bug, hence the `notnull` hack):

```
In [16]: pd.get_dummies(s1[s1.notnull()])
Out[16]: 
   a  c
0  1  0
1  1  0
3  0  1
4  0  1
5  0  1
```

*If you wanted to include these results you could use a different placeholder(e.g. `'_'`).*

Comment: Oh cripes it looks like there is a bug in `get_dummies`, it's not ignoring the NaN but rather doing something strange...